# My heroku app redirects to another site

Tags: heroku

this week one of my client sent me an email saying that the url of the heroku's app was redirecting to another site myapp.com/index.cfm?fa=main.tradelogin. The name of this site is Pressgeek.com.

But if I use myapp.herokuapp.com it works fine. I checked my github repo to see if there was some redirect there but I didn't find any. I also checked the heroku's settings and there were ok.

I never had a problem like this, someone know what to do? Thanks

Comment: What domain are you using to access your Heroku app?

Comment: A godaddy's domain, it is pampaprop.com

Comment: You've got `pampaprop.com` set up with an `A` record (an IP address). [It should be set to a `CNAME` pointing to your Heroku domain `myapp.herokuapp.com`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains).

Comment: In order to redirect your root domain to a Heroku app with a CNAME, your DNS host must support CNAME flattening. See this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain